# Second click on Titanium map Annotation not working

Tags: ios, google-maps, annotations, titanium

I have some annotations on my titanium map.

When I click the annotation A it shows a view. When I click the view it disappears again.

The problem is when I try to click on the same annotation again to show the view again. The click event on the map View is not fired. It only works when I click on an other annotation after hiding the view that vas shown on the click of the annotation A.

this is how I handle click on the annotations. on the first click it is fired, bur on the second click on the same annotation nothing happens.

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    console.log("clicked");
    if (evt.clicksource == 'pin') {
        viewTest.show();
        viewData.show();
        console.log("clicked, id: " + evt.annotation.id);
    }
});
```

this is how i hide my view thats was added on the click of the annotation:

```
viewTransparente.addEventListener('click', function() {
    viewTest.hide();
    viewData.hide();
});
```

In android i works. The only problem is on IOS. The click event is not fired on the second click on the same annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the selected state from the annotation when you click on your view called "`viewTransparente`"

If you log all the properties which i've done below of the annotation you can see that nothing is exposed currently called `selected`:

```
[DEBUG] :      horizontalWrap,
[DEBUG] :      visible,
[DEBUG] :      longitude,
[DEBUG] :      id,
[DEBUG] :      animate,
[DEBUG] :      latitude,
[DEBUG] :      image,
[DEBUG] :      canShowCallout,
[DEBUG] :      annotationTitle
```

A work around for this is to to reset the annotations on the mapView when your view is clicked, though this is a very expensive operation depending on the number of pins you have selected.

```
mapView.annotations = [yourAnnotations];
```

That will remove all of your old annotations and replace them with the new ones, and then the click event will work again because it will have reset the selected state.

I have implemented something similar but I have coded in clustering for the pins enabled on the mapView to stop rendering too many pins and to only render what I need instead of the all the annotations.